# Django per-view caching not caching

Tags: django, caching, heroku, memcached

I am trying to setup per-view caching and have read the docs a few times, though it still doesn't work.

I do see Memcache being used, but it doesn't seem to be the views as a timestamp I have there is updated.

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'web.middleware.WebMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.http.ConditionalGetMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
)


# Memcache

os.environ['MEMCACHE_SERVERS'] = os.environ.get('MEMCACHIER_SERVERS', '').replace(',', ';')
os.environ['MEMCACHE_USERNAME'] = os.environ.get('MEMCACHIER_USERNAME', '')
os.environ['MEMCACHE_PASSWORD'] = os.environ.get('MEMCACHIER_PASSWORD', '')

CACHES = {
  'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django_pylibmc.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
    'TIMEOUT': 500,
    'BINARY': True,
    'OPTIONS': { 'tcp_nodelay': True }
  }
}

# URL conf

cache_ttl = 24 * 60 * 60

url(r'^categories/$', cache_page(cache_ttl)(main.categories)),

# View

@ensure_csrf_cookie
def categories(request):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are some mistakes in your code :)

1. UpdateCacheMiddleware must be the first middleware and FetchFromCacheMiddleware must be the last (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache)
2. Dont know if 'django_pylibmc' is a shortcut in your cachebackend but in my settings it is "django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache"

Maybe that helps.

Comment: Are the middleware required even for perview caching?